# How to use certificates

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

How to handle the following error while using certificates:

```
> CertEnroll::CX509Enrollment::_CreateRequest: Access is denied.
> 0x80070005 (WIN32: 5 ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)
```

Comment: Are you using templates for request Generation? There are also ACLs...